# Как в php, кнопку "выбрать файл" и "загрузить" объединить в одну кнопку?

Tags: php, html

Нужно объединить кнопку выбора файла и загрузки, что бы пользователь сразу мог загружать картинку после её выбора. Как это правильно реализовать?

```
  <div id="block_1" <? if(isset($_POST['send'])){?>style="display:block"<?}?>>
  <div></div>
  <div id="block_2">


    <?php

    if (isset($_POST['send'])) {

      $dir = './image';

      $f = scandir($dir);

      foreach ($f as $file){
        if(preg_match('/\.(jpg)/', $file)){




          $time_file = date("U", filectime($file));
          $time = date('U');
          $time_match = $time - $time_file;

          $delete_time = 1 * 60 * 24;

      //echo " (".$time_match."сек ) ";

          if ($time_match > $delete_time) {
            unlink($file);
        //echo "Файл удалён";
          }
      //echo "<br />";




        }
      }



      $new_name = md5(time().rand(0, 500)).'.jpg';
      setcookie('url_door', $new_name, time()+3600, '/');
      $_COOKIE['url_door'] = $new_name;

  ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '6M'); //ограничение в 6 мб
  if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST" ) {

    if ($_FILES['inputfile']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK && ($_FILES['inputfile']['type'] == 'image/jpeg' || $_FILES['inputfile']['type'] == 'image/png' || $_FILES['inputfile']['type'] == 'image/gif')) { 




  $destiation_dir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/image' . $new_name; // директория для размещения файла
  if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['inputfile']['tmp_name'], $destiation_dir)) { //перемещение в желаемую директорию
  //Файл загружен //оповещаем пользователя об успешной загрузке файла
  } else {
  //Файл не загружен
  }
} else {
  switch ($_FILES['inputfile']['error']) {
    case UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE:
    case UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE:
  //Файл превышает ограничение
    brake;
    case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE:
  //Файл не выбран
    break;
    default:
  //Что-то пошло не так!
  }
 }
}
}
if(isset($_COOKIE['url_door'])){                                 
  $cookie_file = $_COOKIE['url_door'];                                      
} 
?>
<?
if(isset($_COOKIE['url_door'])){
$cookie_file = $_COOKIE['url_door'];
} else {
$background_image = "/source/background_img/background_img.jpg";
}
?>

<div class="block" style="background: url('<? echo $background_image ?>')0% 100%;background-repeat: no-repeat; margin-top: 16px; margin-left: -20px; width: 890px; height: 454px;">
<p>
<input style="display:none;" type="checkbox" checked="1" id="drawSkeleton"></input>
<label style="display:none;" for="drawSkeleton">Draw control points.</label>
</p>
</div>
<div id="download_form">
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form_send_file">
<div class="fileform">
<input style="z-index: -1;" type="file" id="inputfile" name="inputfile" value="Выбрать файл">
<input type="submit" id="input_button" value="Загрузить" name="send">
</div>
</form>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Это не в PHP, это Javascript (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7321855/how-do-i-auto-submit-an-upload-form-when-a-file-is-selected):

document.getElementById("file").onchange = function() {
    document.getElementById("form").submit();
};

Answer (score 0):

Присвойте форме id, и добавьте в атрибут файла событие `onchange`

```html
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form_send_file" id='form_send_file'>
<div class="fileform">
<input onchange="document.getElementById('form_send_file').submit()" style="z-index: -1;" type="file" id="inputfile" name="inputfile" value="Выбрать файл">
</div>
</form>
```